# should I change my seatpost?

Tags: suspension, seatpost

I have a seatpost with spring suspension. Something like this one: [image: seatpost with spring suspension]
A friend of mine hit it with his leg while he was dismounting and broke it into two pieces. After putting it back, I noticed that the plastic piece that holds it together has a broken thread. The bike is about 1 month old, so it is still under warranty.

Should I leave it as it is and hope for the best, or should I go back to store and ask for a new one, alleging bad manufacture?

Also a plastic ring it is clearly to weak for that join should I just get a simple seatpost ?

Comment: How did it break when the rider was dismounting?  Some detail is not being said there.

Comment: @Criggie he hit the seat whit his leg. He was quite drunk and didn't get out like usually it was a fast and really portal coordinated movement. Think about getting out your bike by passing you leg over the seat. And now thing that you are a drunk 90 kg guy who forget separate his leg from the seat before rising it.

Comment: It must have been cracked almost totally then - I can't imagine a tap with a leg could break it.  Even stomping on a seat post over two rocks should barely bend it.

Comment: @Criggie I was really surprised too but the post looks fine it is have only that plastic ring damaged. That is why I even consider to let it be.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the cushion of the seat post, you could request a new one, especially if it keeps coming apart. It should be covered under the warranty. If you don't care about the spring support, a simple seat post will be more sturdy.